# How do I get best odoo rest api documentation?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

Please share odoo rest api documentation for beginners...using python

Comment: Odoo has absolutely terrible documentation of their REST/JsonRpc/XmlRpc APIs! It's a nightmare trying to find out how to do things, what functions to call, what are their arguments, what are possible values for the args, etc etc. It's just a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see official one? Or you looks for something else?  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html

Comment: Hi Thanks, using odoo api url..I have to implement in another framework...so which one I should follow